# Disable selection of a cell without UserInteractionEnabled in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a cell with a button and setting `UserInteractionEnabled` to false disables the button too. Now if I use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None`. Although the cell doesn't get highlighted but I loose the previous selected cell. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: Do you want to be able to select multiple cells then?

Comment: No just one. but not the cell with button in it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement the `UITableView` delegate method

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?
```

Return `nil` for the row you don't want to be able to be selected.

Comment: Check the updated code. Still losing the selected row

Comment: Do you mean indexPath.row == 0

Answer (score 1):

... and for Swift 3, the delegate method is:

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        return indexPath
    }
}
```